# I have a bike that I would love to know what kind

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image][image]

I have a bike that I would love to know what kind it is if anyone can help it would be grateful..  The serial number is 0960668010 and I can fix it anywhere

Comment: The serial number isn't much use. Unlike cars, they're not globally unique and each company just uses its own scheme. If you'd already narrowed it down to a small number of companies, the serial number might help but you can't just look at the serial and say what company it is. Most BMXes are just generic frames made by no-name Chinese companies. If you like the frame, add components to turn it into a full bike. it's very unlikely to be valuable so the knowing actual manufacturer  almost certainly makes no difference.

Comment: What kind of bike is it? It’s a BMX

Comment: There are zillions of BMX frames around. Why do people so much want to know what make/age/value is their particular frame?

Answer (score 2):

It is a BMX bike frame.

BMX bikes are typically used for tricks and acrobatics. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMX

The very narrow parallelogram shape of the frame and the small wheel diametres are typical for BMX bikes.
The short reach and peculiar shape of the stem also points to BMX.

@RoboKaren already added a BMX tag and mentioned it in the comments.